# DropdownList Data Annotation does not fire when the Textboxes and other controls are firing

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, data-annotations

I have a form that has several controls in it. I added data annotation to display an error message to the user when the required field are left empty. The TextBoxes and other controls display the message, which is an "*" before the label name, but the dropdownlist does not not. Once the user get rid of all the error messages and click on submit again, then, the message for the dropdown box is display. How do I force the dropdown box to display the message at the same time with the textbox?

Additional information:
Here is a sample of my data annotation:

```
    [MetadataType(typeof(UserMetaData))]
    public partial class UserMeta
    {
    }
 public class UserMetaData
        {
            [Required(ErrorMessage = "*")] 
            public int GenderID { get; set; } 

    //The gender ID is displayed in a dropdown 
    list with "Select" as the default option. Then, it has all the other genders
     showing in the dropdown once it is clicked on.

                [Required(ErrorMessage = "*")]
                public DateTime DataOfBirth{ get; set; } 
               }

In my view, I am using 
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DataOfBirth) //This is working fine.

@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.GenderID) 
//Here is the dropdown
    @Html.DropDownList("GenderID", null, "Select", new { style = "width:200px;", onchange = "ValidateDropdown()" })
//This is the one that is not working as expected. I could get it to work using javascript, but I am trying not to it if I there is a way to get it to work properly using data annotation. 

Thank in advance for your help.
```

Comment: Does your DropDownList include the "Select item" text? I mean, the one set in the DropDownList, not one in the list of items.  I found that if you don't provide the label text as the first item... it doesn't fire the client side check.

Comment: It is not set in the list of item. I added it to the dropdownlist on the client side. I updated the original questions to include the dropdownlist.

Comment: What does the "onchange=ValidateDropdown()" function?  If you rely on DataAnnotations... and use the jQuery.validator it does the validation for you.

Comment: I added the client side validation as a second option in case I have to go that route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not get it to work properly on the server side. As a result, I had to write a JQuery function that does the validation for the dropdown on the client side. Then, I do the post only if there is a selection on the dropdown.